# Can you use SendGrid's PHP v5.5.1 API with the username and password instead of API Key

Tags: php, api, sendgrid

I have the below code that I want to use with my local version SendGrid. The only problem is it is not excepting my password. After researching I found that the password is completely different than the API Key. I am not able to update the API Key because the mail will not send on my live production server while updating this.

My code on my local is as follows:

```
 <?php
require '../database/vendor/autoload.php';
// If you are not using Composer
// require("path/to/sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php");
$from = new SendGrid\Email(null, "test@test.com");
$subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
$to = new SendGrid\Email(null, "test@test.com");
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);
//$apiKey = getenv('xxxxxx');
//$apiKey = "xxxxxx";
$sg = new \SendGrid("xxxxxx");
$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
echo $response->statusCode();
print_r($response->headers());
echo $response->body();
?>
```

However I keep getting the following error:
The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked=

Comment: If your server isn't sending mail right now anyway, why can't you update to an API Key, which will then allow it to work?

Comment: I was saying the mail will not work once I update the api key. That is not the case though as I found out you can create multiple api keys. After, digging and searching, I found out that because we were running version 1 of SendGrid we never had an api key to begin with.  Even if we did you can create multiple api keys that do not conflict with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I found out you can create multiple api keys. After, digging and searching, I found out that because we were running version 1 of SendGrid we never had an api key to begin with.  Even if we did, you can create multiple api keys that do not conflict with each other. Also, it looks like you use username and password only if using versions prior to V3 of SendGrid